# Can I filter a parent model by occurences in a child model in django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have two models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # stuff


class Task(models.Model):
    # stuff
```

When assigning new tasks to users, I want to avoid assigning tasks the worker has gotten before. The approach I'm trying to take is to add a third model, `Assignment` that tracks tasks assigned to a given user:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(User)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
```

How, though, do I go about forming a query based on this? My thought was to start by filtering Assignments by the user being assigned to, but I'm getting stuck after that point.

```
def get_tasks(worker):
    previous_assignments = Assignment.objects.filter(worker=worker)
    # then something like...
    assignable_tasks = Task.objects.exclude(pk__in=previous_assignments.task)  #clearly wrong
```

Is there a way to access the task ids inside the `previous_assignments` queryset? Not sure if this isn't the best approach, or if I am just missing how to move past this step.

**Edit**: It occurs to me I could populate an empty set with `Task`s by looping through those `Assignment` objects and then use an `__in` exclude argument like above... Any better approaches than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to exclude with `pk_in`, you would need a list or queryset of task ids to exclude. For example you could do:

```
previous_assignments = Assignment.objects.filter(worker=worker).values_list('task_id')
assignable_tasks = Task.objects.exclude(pk__in=previous_assignments)
```

However you don't need to do this. You can use the double underscore notation to follow the relationship from assignment to worker:

```
assignable_tasks = Task.objects.exclude(assignment__worker=worker)
```

Note that you could use a many-to-many field instead, and Django will take care of creating the joining table for you:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

In this case, your query becomes:

```
assignable_tasks = Task.objects.exclude(users=worker)
```

Comment: `assignable_tasks = Task.objects.exclude(assignment__worker=worker)` beautiful. Somehow I didn't realize you could follow a child -> parent relationship like that (in that assignment is a child of task). I can't use a ManyToManyField because I'm also storing when the task was assigned in that table so that I can fall back to the oldest task if there are no unassigned ones left. Thanks much!

Comment: You can use a many-to-many field with the `through` argument. See the docs on [extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: Oh perfect - I may go down that road. Appreciate all the help.